# Spring test context best practice

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, spring-boot, spring-test

I'm trying to cover a huge Spring Boot application with integration tests. There are lots of Spring beans within the app. It takes a while to load the Spring context.

So I'm wondering -

- *Is Spring clever enough to share the same context between multiple integration tests located in different classes?* I mean to avoid initializing the heavy-weight context for each test class.
- *What happens when tests 1,2,4 use `TestContextOne` and tests 3,5 use `TestContextTwo`? Does Spring launch them in 1,2,4,3,5 order? Or does Spring keep two contexts in memory?*

***P.S.*** In other words, *is the common practice to use a single "full" Spring Context for all integration tests, instead of writing separate ones for each test?*

Comment: If you haven't hacked around with weird things yourself in theory it should only load 2 contexts.

Comment: @M.Deinum so the common practice is to use one "full" context for all integration tests, right?

Comment: It depends  do you want a unit, integration or system test. You could perfectly well write an integration test (for a single component) and then only bootstrap that component (with its dependencies) when doing a system test you would want the whole system up and running.

Comment: @M. Deinum yeah,  each test involve only few components.  But I'm afraid that settup hundred of different small test contexts is more expensive than a single big context

Answer (score 15):

One of the main features provided by spring framework for testing an application is the context caching mechanism to avoid exactly what you mention about the load overhead. The spring documentation says that:

> Once the TestContext framework loads an `ApplicationContext` (or `WebApplicationContext`) for a test, that context will be cached and reused for all subsequent tests that declare the same unique context configuration within the same test suite.

With this affirmation in mind you have to understand how the cache mechanism works to determine the best strategy on build your tests. The question here is: `When spring caches the context, it stores this context in memory using what key?`. According to documentation, the key is based on some parameters of the container:

> An `ApplicationContext` can be uniquely identified by the combination of configuration parameters that are used to load it. Consequently, the unique combination of configuration parameters are used to generate a `key` under which the context is cached. The TestContext framework uses the following configuration parameters to build the context cache key:
>
> `locations` (from @ContextConfiguration)
> `classes` (from @ContextConfiguration)
> `contextInitializerClasses` (from @ContextConfiguration)
> `contextCustomizers` (from ContextCustomizerFactory)
> `contextLoader` (from @ContextConfiguration)
> `parent` (from @ContextHierarchy)
> `activeProfiles` (from @ActiveProfiles)
> `propertySourceLocations` (from @TestPropertySource)
> `propertySourceProperties` (from @TestPropertySource)
> `resourceBasePath` (from @WebAppConfiguration)

Based on this information I may suggest you that the best practice is organize your tests in a way that they use the same set of context parameters (that is,  the same cache key) to benefit from cache mechanism and avoid another context to be loaded. Spring documentation also gives an example:

> ..., if `TestClassA` specifies `{"app-config.xml", "test-config.xml"}` for the locations (or value) attribute of @ContextConfiguration, the `TestContext` framework will load the corresponding `ApplicationContext` and store it in a static context cache under a key that is based solely on those locations. So if `TestClassB` also defines `{"app-config.xml", "test-config.xml"}` for its locations (either explicitly or implicitly through inheritance) but does not define `@WebAppConfiguration`, a different `ContextLoader`, different active profiles, different context initializers, different test property sources, or a different parent context, **then the same `ApplicationContext` will be shared by both test classes**. This means that the setup cost for loading an application context is incurred only once (per test suite), and subsequent test execution is much faster.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick that you can use in your integration tests is to force all the beans in the context to be "lazy". This is really useful when running just one integration test, as you do not have to wait for the entire application context to be loaded and initialized. This can significantly improve the time it takes to run a single test.

You may run into situations where beans are being implicitly created (Example: Spring IntegrationFlow). The flow is never directly injected into anything but your classes may have references to beans that the flow creates. In this case you either need to @Autowire your flow (to insure the implicit beans get created) or you can get creative with a BeanPostProcessor.

I created the following post processor and you just have to add it to your testing spring context.

```
public class LazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {

    private Class<?>[] exclusionList;

    public LazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
    }

    public LazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor(Class<?>[] exclusionList) {
        this.exclusionList = exclusionList;
    }

    @Override
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

        //Iterate over all bean, mark them as lazy if they are not in the exclusion list.
        for (String beanName : beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames()) {
            if (isLazy(beanName, beanFactory)) {
                BeanDefinition definition = beanFactory.getBeanDefinition(beanName);
                definition.setLazyInit(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isLazy(String beanName, ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        if (exclusionList == null || exclusionList.length == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        for (Class<?> clazz : exclusionList) {
            if (beanFactory.isTypeMatch(beanName,clazz)) {
                return false;
            } 
        } 
        return true;        
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class MyTest {
.
.
.
@TestConfiguration
protected static class TestConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessor lazyBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Or you extend it with exclusions (In this example, any bean that is assignable to a Spring Integration flow will NOT be marked as lazy:

```
@TestConfiguration
protected static class TestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public BeanFactoryPostProcessor lazyBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new ExtendedTestLazyBeanFactoryPostProcessor();
    }


    static private class ExtendedTestLazyBeanFactoryPostProcessor extends LazyInitBeanFactoryPostProcessor {    
        public ServiceTestLazyBeanFactoryPostProcessor() {
            super(new Class<?>[] {IntegrationFlow.class});
        }   
    }
```